# About script of function

Tags: javascript, function, call

I have difficulties to understand this part of code:

```
"use strict";

let v = ["sept","huit","neuf","dix","valet","dame","roi","as"];
let c = ["pique","coeur","trèfle","carreau"];

function creerCarte( v, c){



}

let test = creerCarte("neuf", "trèfle");
console.log(test["valeur"]);  // must show "neuf" on console
console.log(test["couleur"]);  // must show "trèfle" on console
```

I don't understand the call of the function via the variable:

```
console.log(test["valeur"]);
```

What is `["valeur"]`, what is it used for?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You declared `test` as the return value of the `creerCarte` function, but that function doesn't do anything right now.

Comment: You should probably run through an introductory JavaScript tutorial. `test["valeur"]` means access the `valeur` key of the `test` [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I would guess their task is to implement that function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Since the two keys used don't match any values in the arrays, there is no way to come up with an algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus why would you need an algorithm? It's just putting the two parameters in an object; the arrays seem irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's the point, they *seem* irrelevant, but yet, they are part of the assignment. We just don't have enough information to make any reasonable assumptions on this. The question should be clarified or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete creerCarte function to return an object.
However I don't know what your code needs to do.

test["valeur"] means, get the property of test object which is named "valeur".

For example:

test = {
  valeur: 'something'
}

You will get back 'something' with test['valeur'].

Comment: Again, this is not an answer. It's a guess since we don't know what the goal is. This should be a comment.

Comment: What is ["valeur"], what is it used for?
That was the question, what I answered.

Comment: Please take some time to look at other answers (especially the accepted ones) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). We don't provide answers to poor quality questions as it just encourages more poor questions.

Comment: Thank you, I found it after more than an hour of research, it was simple and I wanted to make complicated ...
it was enough to simply create an object in the function and return the object